# TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ Functionality

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Any one have any idea how 'TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ' function works internally in oracle.

I want to know how it converts timestamp to timezone

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm) is very handy for questions like this.

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ converts a string into a timestamp with timezone information. It doesn't convert something that's already a timestamp into a timestamp with timezone information, without first having a conversion back into a string - which, as I'm sure you're aware, you should always do explicitly.

Comment: i know what it does want to check how oracle has  implemented. Any basic idea how they re converting it

Comment: Well, not exactly, since its proprietary code. However, all it does is take your string and format mask, and match up the two, so it can say which bit of the string matches to which bit of the time stamp format,